# Issues creating foreign key in Xampp/phpmyadmin

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

this is my piece of code ..

```
ALTER TABLE ADDRESS
ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES  CUSTOMER (ID)
```

I created constraints in SQL YoG but in xampp it shows some issues. Any suggestion

[image]

Comment: If ID is unique, why do you add FK on this field? Foreign key assumes multiple values.

Comment: @Devart wait... what? All foreign keys **have** to be defined as referring to a unique record. An address must always have a 1-to-1 relation with a customer. The customer on the other hand can be referred by multiple addresses hence a m-to-1 relation. Which reminds me...

Comment: The given example ('FOREIGN KEY (ID)' where ID is unique) supposes 1-to-1 relation, where one customer has one address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Foreign key checklist:

- both tables must be InnoDB; recently (MySQL 5.5.5) started shipping InnoDB as the default;
- both columns must be defined with the same datatype

  - including length;
  - including `UNSIGNED` qualifiers;
- the referenced key must be `UNIQUE`;
- the referenced key must not be `NULL`-able;

Comment: Everything is fine. still same error. i need to give engine=InnoDB ??? because it shows `Can't create table 'calsoft.#sql-7d0_30c' (errno: 150) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=e86ba837afbc681c0928b72b4ab7fd35">Details...</a>)`

Comment: The two tables should already be InnoDB, it they weren't then a correct syntax would just be ignored, it would not trigger an error.

Comment: finally i deleted the id from parent table and create new one. now its working thanks for your help. Im voting up ur response :) Cheers